Authentication with Bearer token with wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk
I'm running wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk in ubuntu-frame on Ubuntu 22.04.
This setup will be used on several sites and will display information related to that location. The web server backend needs an authentication token (bearer token) to allow communication.
Is it possible to send a bearer token in the http GET request header?
Are there other browser variants available for ubuntu-frame like Firefox, Chrome, Chromium, Edge or opera?
My previous solution was based on Chrome and Chromedriver.

I'm not familiar with wpe-webkit-mir-kiosk, I'd guess there would be a way, but in general, in case nobody comes up with the answer, there are ways to work around this that should work, such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/154641/4316166 (i.e. set up a local proxy to wrap requests and forward them to the backend)

Ah, or using a burp-compatible browser and do it like hackers do.
